# Django display Foreign Key reference in Template

Tags: django, django-models, jinja2

I'm trying to develop an application in django. I have a general `Publication` table that may or may be not linked to a `Project` model.

Here is some code :

#### Project

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    abstract = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    link = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### Publication

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    authors_string = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now the problem is that I'm trying to display this reference in the template. How can I do that?
publication.project.title seems not to work. In general publication seems not to have a project field

#### Template

```
{% for p in projects %}
    <option value="">{{ p.title }}</option>
    {% if p.projects.id %}
        <option>{{ p.title }}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What am I missing?

#### Edit

```
@login_required
def profile(request, initial_page=1):

    # Get query params
    offset = (initial_page-1) * 10
    limit = offset + 10

    # Handle default GET request
    current_user = request.user
    pending_publications = Publication.objects.filter(authors=current_user).order_by('-year')
    number_of_pending_publications = Publication.objects.filter(authors=current_user).count()
    number_of_pending_pages = int(number_of_pending_publications/10) + 1
    confirmed_publications = Publication.objects.filter(authors2=current_user).order_by('-year')
    number_of_confirmed_publications = Publication.objects.filter(authors2=current_user).count()
    number_of_confirmed_pages = int(number_of_confirmed_publications/10) + 1
    projects = Project.objects.all()

    if (number_of_confirmed_publications % 10) == 0:
        number_of_confirmed_pages -=1 
    if (number_of_pending_publications % 10) == 0:
        number_of_pending_pages -=1

    # Set up form defaults
    default_form_values = {
        "first_name" : request.user.first_name, 
        "last_name" : request.user.last_name,
        "email" : request.user.email, 
        "organization" : request.user.organization,
        "bio" : request.user.bio,
    }

    # Set up context variables for html
    context = {
        'form': UpdateProfileForm(initial = default_form_values),
        'projects' : projects,
        'confirmed_publications' : confirmed_publications[offset:limit],
        'number_of_confirmed_publications' : number_of_confirmed_publications,
        'number_of_confirmed_pages' : number_of_confirmed_pages,
        'pending_publications' : pending_publications[offset:limit],
        'number_of_pending_publications' : number_of_pending_publications,
        'number_of_pending_pages' : number_of_pending_pages,
        'initial_pending_page' : initial_page,
        'initial_confirmed_page' : 1,

    }

    # Render page
    return render(request, 'main/publication.html', context)
```

Comment: can you show your view?

Comment: You haven't shown us your `Project` model, but does it have an attribute called `projects`? `{% if p.projects.id %}`

Comment: Django creates an id field if it’s not specified? Using projects.title may be the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are handling a 1 -> n relationship. In order to access the properties of your `Publication` instances from a `Project` instance you either need to call `yourmodel_set` or provide a related name.

**1. Using _set**

Supposing you have a `Project` instance in your view and would like to iterate over all related Publications this would be e.g

```
for pub in project.publication_set.all():
    print(pub.title)
```

In a template using the django template language this would be (using your template):

```
{% for p in projects %}
{{ p.title }}
    {% for pub in p.publication_set.all %}
    {{ pub.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**2. Using a related name**

If you do not like the _set thing you can add a related name and use this to access the related objects.

In your models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    authors_string = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='publications')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and then in your template

```
{% for p in projects %}
    {{ p.title }}
        {% for pub in p.publications.all %}
        {{ pub.title }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to access a Project from a `Publication`, the syntax you stated is correct, e.g:

```
pub.project.title
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks. I think there are two typo in your answer because code for me works only with `p.publication_set.all()` and not with `p.publication_set.all`. Stack overflow won't let me edit the post because requires at least 6 character to be modified.

Comment: @MarioRossi Are you sure? The django template language syntax requires omitting the ```()``` while in your python code you must of course use the ```()```.

Comment: No you are right. Completely my fault. Thanks again